# Maximizing the volume of the convex hull of $N$ points in the unit ball

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, combinatorial-geometry, convex-geometry

Suppose we are given an integer $N\ge4$, and we have to pick $N$ points in a unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$ to maximize the volume of their [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). Are those points necessarily on the surface of the ball? Can we generalize the result to $\mathbb R^n$?

For the similar problem in $\mathbb R^2$ the answer seems obvious: we always have to pick the vertices of a regular $N$-gon inscribed in the disk, so they always lie on the disk boundary.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding the question, but if one of the points $P$ is interior to the ball can it not be extended along the radius containing it to the point $P^\prime$ on the surface of the ball to form a convex hull with greater volume?

Comment: Or perhaps the difficulty arises in showing that the new convex hull contains the old as a subset?

Comment: Note that by increasing all pairwise distances in a set of points it is actually possible to decrease the volume of their convex hull.

Comment: I see, obviously I am out of my level here. But it is an interesting problem, I will continue to think about and try to see why my suggested solution does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a point $Q$ in the interior of the convex hull of points $P_1,\cdots,P_N$ and extend the rays $QP_k$ to the points $P_k^\prime$ on the surface of the ball to get a convex hull containing the old yet with volume not less than the old.

Comment: Note that if point $A$ is in Conv$\{P_i\}$ then there are $P_j,P_k$ such that $A$ lies on the segment $P_jP_k$, thus $A$ also must lie in the convex hull of segments $P_jP_j^\prime$ and $P_kP_k^\prime$ therefore $A$ is also in Conv$\{P_i^\prime\}$. So Conv$\{P_i\}\subseteq$Conv$\{P_i^\prime\}$.

Comment: "not less" only means the points can be picked on the surface, not that they are necessarily on the surface. Note that, for example, without the requirement $N\ge4$ the answer to my question would be "no".